# Code-word length of given maximal length

Tags: coding-theory

> If the maximum allowable code-word length is $672$ bits and assuming we are using an LDPC parity check matrix with rate $1/2$, $3/4$, what is the maximal number of data bits in each LDPC code-word?

My solution is that $\text{max} = 3*672/4$, but the correct answer provided in the book is $168$ Does anyone know why this is the answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an $(n,k)$ code, the parity check matrix is an $(n-k)\times n $ matrix. Then,
a parity check matrix with ratio 3/4 means $\frac{n-k}{n}=\frac{3}{4}$, i.e., the code rate, which is defined as $\frac{k}{n}$, is  $\frac{1}{4}$. Then, it is easy to see that  $672\times \frac{1}{4}= 168$  bits.

Comment: thanks, so when we say parity matrix with ratio 3/4, do we mean to say that for each 4 bits we add one redundant bit extra ( i.e rate 1/4)?

Comment: what about with rate 1/2? it is a lower rate or faster than 3/4 ie more redundant bits correct?

Comment: In general, a code rate $\frac{k}{n}$ means for each $k$ bits we add $n-k$ redundant bits.

Comment: First find the code rate and discuss based on that. As, mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: I have one more question if you dont mind. Are parity check matrices fixed matrices? For example if someone wants a code rate of 1/4 for maximal codeword of 672. Does that mean I can use only one fixed H parity matrix or do we have to solve for the parity matrix? @Bob

Comment: No, there can be many parity check matrices for a given code rate. Specifically, in LDPC codes the  parity check matrices are generated randomly (pseud-randomly).